# Django query spaning relationships with latest

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder)

class Percentage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

With only `folder.id` how do I get the **latest** `percentage` for each `project` attached to the `folder` and then find the mean percentage for the `folder`?

Comment: How about `Percentage.objects.filter(project__folder__id=folder_id).latest()` ?

Comment: That would only get me the latest percentage for all projects attached to the `file` :( I wanted to get the latest percentage for **EACH** `project` attached to the `file`